# controller use $scope? custom service use this?

Tags: angularjs

I found in Controller, we use $scope, here is the link (http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_controller).
I change $scope to this, it cannot work.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
</script>
```

However, I found in Service, we use this, here is the link (http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_services_custom).
In hexafy service, I change this to $scope, it cannot work.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.service('hexafy', function() {
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return x.toString(16);
    }
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, hexafy) {
  $scope.hex = hexafy.myFunc(255);
});
</script>
```

Does my above summary correct? If not, what should be correct summary considering all kinds of possible.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **this** instead of **$scope** in controller as well. They have brought in **controller as** syntax(from Angular 1.2). You can attach data to **this**(Here controller holds the data). But internally it will be attached to $scope only, but you don't have to attach it manually. It has to be declared in html like this , controller is declared as **main** , so we have to refer to data in html using **main**.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
   {{ main.title }}
</div>

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  this.title = 'Some title'; 
  console.log("Title" + $scope.main.title); // It will print some title in the console.
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I got. However, can we use $scope instead of this in Service?

Comment: Yeah you can use it

Comment: Thanks. I tried, it works. For Serice and Controller, which one you suggest, this or $scope?

Comment: For binding of data, its better we use 'this' rather than $scope

Comment: Does it mean 'this' not limited to scope? For example,
{{main.name}}
<div ng-controller='myCtrl'></div>

Comment: I didnt get ur question ?

Comment: I tried, it cannot work if my {{main.name}} is out of <div ng-controller='myCtrl'></div>

Comment: No it wont work outside of this <div ng-controller='myCtrl'></div> , it has to be inside that div

Comment: If so, I did not see any advantage using 'this'?

Comment: Go through this article for understanding the advantage , https://toddmotto.com/a-better-way-to-scope-angular-extend-no-more-vm-this/